# Sequence Number generation between multiple tags

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

My Input xml is in below format

```
<root>
    <entity>
        <entityrecord>
            <field>
                <id>Parent</id>
                <value>P-1</value>
            </field>
            <entity>
                <entityrecord>
                    <field>
                        <id>Child</id>
                        <value>C-1</value>
                    </field>
                </entityrecord>
                <entityrecord>
                    <field>
                        <id>Child</id>
                        <value>C-2</value>
                    </field>
                </entityrecord>
            </entity>
        </entityrecord>
        <entityrecord>
            <field>
                <id>Parent</id>
                <value>P-2</value>
            </field>
            <entity>
                <entityrecord>
                    <field>
                        <id>Child</id>
                        <value>C-1</value>
                    </field>
                </entityrecord>
                <entityrecord>
                    <field>
                        <id>Child</id>
                        <value>C-2</value>
                    </field>
                </entityrecord>
                <entityrecord>
                    <field>
                        <id>Child</id>
                        <value>C-3</value>
                    </field>
                </entityrecord>
            </entity>
        </entityrecord>
        <entityrecord>
            <field>
                <id>Parent</id>
                <value>P-3</value>
            </field>
            <entity>
                <entityrecord>
                    <field>
                        <id>Child</id>
                        <value>C-1</value>
                    </field>
                </entityrecord>
                <entityrecord>
                    <field>
                        <id>Child</id>
                        <value>C-2</value>
                    </field>
                </entityrecord>
                <entityrecord>
                    <field>
                        <id>Child</id>
                        <value>C-3</value>
                    </field>
                </entityrecord>
            </entity>
        </entityrecord>
    </entity>
</root>
```

and my output Format should be

```
1^P-1
2^C-1
3^C-2
4^P-2
5^C-1
6^C-2
7^C-3
8^P-3
9^C-1
10^C-2
11^C-3
```

I tried Many different methods to get this done but nothing worked out.I was not able to generate the sequence number.can anyone help me out in this case

Comment: Can you also post your code?

Comment: Please explain your logic in words. Why is the number 6 repeated? -- P.S. Pick either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Comment: {1^P-1
2^C-1
3^C-2
4^P-2
5^C-1
6^C-2
7^C-3
8^P-3
9^C-1
10^C-2
11^C-3}

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: @ michael.hor257k 2 times 6 is a mistake, it should be 6, 7 ,8 and so on, and to explain the logic , I need to generate sequence number With first parent as 1 and childs as 2,3 . and then 2nd parent as 4 and its childs as 5,6,7. then 3rd parent as 8 and its childs as 9,10,11 and so on if we have more records , XSLT2.0 would be be better

Comment: @VeerelliAbhishek Is your question not answered (the answer is the same for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0)?

Comment: Yes it Works great,although I was expecting to do generation with templates instead of count. so that i can use it for different things.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the repeating 6 in the provided output is a mistake, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:number count="field" level="any"/>
    <xsl:text>^</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the result will be:

```
1^P-1
2^C-1
3^C-2
4^P-2
5^C-1
6^C-2
7^C-3
8^P-3
9^C-1
10^C-2
11^C-3
```